# Norm $C^1$ multivariate functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Given an open and bounded subset $\,\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\,$ and the interval $\,[0,T]\,$ such that $\,T<\infty$, I'm trying to find a norm for $\,X=\mathcal{C}^1\left([0,T]\times\Omega\right)$ such that $X$ is a Banach space.

I know the norm for one variable functions is
$$\|f\|_{\,\mathcal{C}^1\left([0,T]\right)}=\|f(t)\|_\infty+\|f'(t)\|_\infty$$
so I tried this for $\,u=u(x,t),\;(x,t)\in\Omega\times[0,T]$
$$\|u\|_{X}=\max_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{\infty}+\max_{0\leq t\leq T}\|\,|Du|(\cdot,t)\,\|_{\infty}$$
where $\,|\cdot|\,$ denotes the modulus.

But honestly, I'm not sure this is correct.                                Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The object $\max_{0\leq t\leq T}\|u\|_{{C}^1\left(\Omega\right)}$ is not well defined since the thing we're taking the max of is not a function of $T$. Likewise for the second term in the definition.

Comment: To be precise those objects ARE well-defined but since the $T$ doesn't appear inside it reduces to $$\|u\|_{X}=\|u\|_{{C}^1\left(\Omega\right)}+\|\,|Du|\,\|_{{C}^1\left(\Omega\right)}$$ so I suspect there is something gone wrong here.

Comment: @Daron: I've edited the question, maybe I didn't explain myself properly. How about now?